# d3js Chart Animations not functioning

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

I'm working at applying transitions to my graph. But I'm struggling to get them to produce any results. I'm trying to follow the `.enter()`, `.update()`, `.exit()` pattern.

What I want accomplished is to have one series of data disappear. I'd like it to happen when an individual clicks on the legend (to select/deselect), but right now, for ease - I attached the function to a button. After selecting the button, all green bars would come into view, and all blue bars would leave.

The part that confuses me about this, is this is a paired bar chart. So things have been grouped in sets, and added an extra layer of complexity.

```
d3.select("#change").on("click", updateBars);
function updateBars()
{   

xScale.domain(d3.range(dataset.length)).rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);
yScale.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return (d.local > d.global) ? d.local : d.global;})]); 

var bars = svg.selectAll("sets")
    .data(dataset);

bars.enter()
    .attr("x", w)
    .attr("y", function(d){ 
        return h - yScale(d.global);
    })
    .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", function(d){
        return yScale(d.global);
    })
    .attr("fill", colors[0][1])
    ;

//Update
bars.transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return xScale(i);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return h - yScale(d.global);
    })
    .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.global);
    });

//Exit
bars.exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("x", -xScale.rangeBand())
    .remove();
}
```

My full code can also be **[seen here at my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/weXNd/5/)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that with your approach, you can't really use the enter/update/exit selections as intended. You are using your data to create the sets of bars, but then append the individual bars manually without representing them by data items.

I've updated your jsfiddle to provide some form of transition [here](http://jsfiddle.net/weXNd/6/), but to make this work in the proper D3 way, you need to restructure your code. The idea would be to create both sets of bars using just the data, i.e. something like

```
d3.selectAll("rect.global").data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "global")
  ...
d3.selectAll("rect.local").data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "local")
  ...
```

Then you can use the same selectAll/data construct to later make individual bars disappear, move, etc. Note that if all you want is to remove one particular kind of bar (like in your jsfiddle), you don't really need all of that -- an approach like the one in my modified jsfiddle is enough.

Only if you want to update the values for the bars, add new ones for a series or remove part of a series you should seriously consider restructuring your code as outlined above.

Comment: Lars to the rescue again. Your suggestion of restructuring the code seems daunting to me. However, I think it would make more sense, & be more consistent with examples online. I assume this would still allow me to keep data paired/grouped?

Comment: Your example works great. But in order to add the series back in, I would need to refactor my code then eh? (that's my assumption being that the series has now been removed from the dom)

Comment: You don't necessarily need to refactor, you could just add it back in the way you added it in the first place. And yes, restructuring the code would still allow you to keep the data grouped -- either in the slightly hacky way I sketched out or by using [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/).